# Renewal process with Bernoulli interarrival times.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X_i,\;i=1,2,\cdots\}$ be i.i.d Bernoulli rvs, i.e. $P\{X_i=x\}=p^x(1-p)^{1-x},\;x\in\{0,1\}$, and $\displaystyle N(t)=\sup_{n}\bigl\{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\leq t\bigr\}$.

How to prove that:

$\displaystyle E[N(t)]\leq \frac{t+1}{p}$

Comment: Answer: By computing $E(N(0))$ and $E(N(t+1)-N(t))$. This should yield that $E(N(t))=(\lfloor t\rfloor+1)/p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Did's tip, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[N(t)] &= \mathbb E[N(\lfloor t\rfloor)]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor t\rfloor}X_k \right]\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\mathbb E[X_k] \\
&= \frac{\lfloor t\rfloor}p\leqslant\frac{t+1}p.
\end{align}